# State of object values when returning from recusrion

Tags: java

Suppose we have the following algorithm for finding min/max in an array using divide an conquer (Courtesy to [Source](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-minimum-maximum-element-array-minimum-comparisons/)):

```
 // A Pair class to wrap immutable primitive ints
class Pair
{
    public int max, min;
 
    public Pair(int max, int min)
    {
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
    }
}
 
class Main
{
    // Divide and conquer solution to find the minimum and maximum number in an array
    public static void findMinAndMax(int[] A, int left, int right, Pair p)
    {
        // if the array contains only one element
 
        if (left == right)                  // common comparison
        {
            if (p.max < A[left]) {          // comparison 1
                p.max = A[left];
            }
 
            if (p.min > A[right]) {         // comparison 2
                p.min = A[right];
            }
 
            return;
        }
 
        // if the array contains only two elements
 
        if (right - left == 1)              // common comparison
        {
            if (A[left] < A[right])         // comparison 1
            {
                if (p.min > A[left]) {      // comparison 2
                    p.min = A[left];
                }
 
                if (p.max < A[right]) {     // comparison 3
                    p.max = A[right];
                }
            }
            else {
                if (p.min > A[right]) {     // comparison 2
                    p.min = A[right];
                }
 
                if (p.max < A[left]) {      // comparison 3
                    p.max = A[left];
                }
            }
 
            return;
        }
 
        // find the middle element
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
 
        // recur for the left subarray
        findMinAndMax(A, left, mid, p);
 
        // recur for the right subarray
        findMinAndMax(A, mid + 1, right, p);
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] A = { 7, 2, 9, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8, 4 };
 
        // initialize the minimum element by `INFINITY` and the
        // maximum element by `-INFINITY`
        Pair p = new Pair(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        findMinAndMax(A, 0, A.length - 1, p);
 
        System.out.println("The minimum array element is " + p.min);
        System.out.println("The maximum array element is " + p.max);
    }
}
```

**Question**: Each time we return from recursion to the caller method from previous step. Will `Pair` object saves it's values `min, max` when returns, given that we delete the method that finishes execution during recursion from the stack please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are loaded in Stack Memory while Objects are loaded in Heap Memory. So completing the method has no impact on the Objects those are created by method. Of that objects is being referred by some current running thread (directly or indirectly) that will stay alive and won't be collected by Garbage Collector.

So answer to your question is Yes. As Pair is being referred so it will stay. And so min and max are still be referred by Pair so that will also stay.

Continuing to that, that is also how PassByReference works. Where you pass an Object from a method to another method (Objects is not immutable and it's not reinitialized and it's not primitive) all the updated in the called method will get reflected in calling method.

As in your case `Pair` is created inside `main` method and being passed to another methods, so till the time main is not finishing it's execution it will stay in heap memory and won't get garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean even if the `pair` object was created inside recusion method it won't be deleted from because it's stored in heap but the one that is deleted if not returned to the caller are variables (float, integer, etc.) is that correct please? However, again objects are stored in the heap and as long as they are used they won't be deleted just to confirm that I understood you correctly please?

Comment: That's right somehow. Because if object (or primitive) is not returned it can be garbage collected any time by the JVM. And as long as objects is being used it won't be deleted (correct term would be it won't get garbage collected and will stay in heap memory).

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not. There is only one instance of `Pair`: the one created in method `main`. The values of `min` and `max` are overwritten as required.